# How do I access the original element from the jQuery wrapper

Tags: javascript, jquery, wrapper

Assuming I have this:

```
var wrap = $("#someId");
```

I need to access the original object that I would get by

```
var orig = document.getElementById("someId");
```

But I don't want to do a `document.getElementById`.

Is there something I can use on `wrap` to get it? something like:

```
var orig = wrap.original();
```

I searched high and low but I didn't find anything; or maybe I'm not looking for the right thing.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The function for this is [`get`](http://api.jquery.com/get).  You can pass an index to `get` to access the element at that index, so `wrap.get(0)` gets the first element (note that the index is 0-based, like an array).  You can also use a negative index, so `wrap.get(-2)` gets the last-but-one element in the selection.

```
wrap.get(0);  // get the first element
wrap.get(1);  // get the second element
wrap.get(6);  // get the seventh element
wrap.get(-1); // get the last element
wrap.get(-4); // get the element four from the end
```

You can also use array-like syntax to access elements, e.g. `wrap[0]`.  However, you can only use positive indexes for this.

```
wrap[0];      // get the first element
wrap[1];      // get the second element
wrap[6];      // get the seventh element
```

Answer (score 5):

`$("#someId")` will return a jQuery object, so to get at the actual HTML element you can do:

`wrap[0]` or `wrap.get(0)`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [get()](http://api.jquery.com/get/) to retrieve the HTML element.

```
var orig = wrap.get(0);
```

However, if `wrap` consists of multiple elements, you will need to know the correct index which to use when you use the `get()` function.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `var orig = wrap[0];` as far as I know, if there's more than one element. If there's just the one, you can just use `wrap` without `$()` around it.

Answer (score -6):

You can use wrap still.. Wrap is the same as 'orig' would be in the above! :)

If you really want:

```
var orig = wrap;
```

Comment: No, this is wrong. A jQuery selection is not the same as a DOM element. The jQuery selection *contains* the DOM element, which is what the question is referring to.

Comment: `$("#someId");` is not the same as `document.getElementById("someId");`